# How to avoid all the components on one activity share the same position?

Tags: android, xml, layout, xamarin.android

I'm trying to implement a `DrawerLayout` but that cause several component fusion together at the beginning of the activity after I add it.
Currently it looks like this:

[image: 1]

Please have in mind than I'm just learning how to implement a `DrawerLayout`.
I make a separated project and it works perfectly and the rest of the code come from the app in which I'm trying to implement this DrawerLeftLayout.

Here is the XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The Main Content View -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <EditText
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/txtNombre" />
            <EditText
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/txtDepto" />
            <RadioGroup
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/radioGroup_CRUD"
                android:layout_marginRight="0.0dp">
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio_Crear"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="(C) Crear" />
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio_Leer"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="(R) Leer" />
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio_Actualizar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="(U) Actualizar" />
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio_Borrar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="(D) Borrar" />
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio_Coords"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Obtener Coords" />
            </RadioGroup>
            <CheckBox
                android:text="Localización en tiempo real"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/cbxTracking" />
            <TextView
                android:text="Coords :"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tvwCoords" />
            <Button
                android:text="Realizar Accion"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/myButton" />
            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/mylistView"
                android:layout_marginTop="0.0dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    <!-- The Left Navigation Drawer -->
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="#818181"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:background="#E3F2Fd" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT:**

They also ask me to try to add the files in xml and add them through main activity, using the SetContentView, the problem with that is it doesn't work:

i love to know how to use xml files in Xamarin Android tho, so if you know how to do it, you maybie have the answer to this question too, (which could or could not happend to be the same)

[http://imgur.com/a/mxxOV](https://imgur.com/a/mxxOV)

**END EDIT**

Questions, comments or anything that helps to find a solution would be much apreciated too

Thanks in advance

Comment: The `DrawerLayout` needs to be the root of the layout and not `LinearLayout`

Comment: Sure, but can you give an example of how to do that?, if you do it in an answer, and it works, i'm giving you the selected answer. ;)

Comment: @akash93 i say this because i don't know how to implement what you say all by myself, thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using RelativeLayout but doesn't specify relative position to each other, better use LinearLayout or learn to use RelativeLayout https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html

Comment: @vbp if you can do a functional example would be cool, specialy if you do with the code i present, because the solution bringed by akash93 doesn't work, if you do it like an answer, and works i'm gonna mark it as the correct one, i'm really having troubles with this matter, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <!-- The Main Content View with the toolbar -->
        <RelativeLayout>
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar/>
            <!-- Rest of the layout -->
        </RelativeLayout>
        <!-- The Left Navigation Drawer -->
        <ListView android:layout_gravity="start" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is how your layout structure is supposed to look like for implementing `DrawerLayout`.I've skipped defining redundant attributes to keep it concise.

From the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r1/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.java)

> DrawerLayout acts as a top-level container for window content that
>   allows for interactive "drawer" views to be pulled out from the edge
>   of the window. Drawer positioning and layout is controlled using the
>   android:layout_gravity attribute on child views corresponding to which
>   side of the view you want the drawer to emerge from: left or right.
>   (Or start/end on platform versions that support layout direction.) To
>   use a DrawerLayout, position your primary content view as the first
>   child with a width and height of match_parent. Add drawers as child
>   views after the main content view and set the layout_gravity
>   appropriately. Drawers commonly use match_parent for height with a
>   fixed width.

In addition, since you seem like a beginner I would strongly suggest that you use Android Studio instead of Visual Studio for android development. It has a lot of useful built-in templates ( Navigation Drawer for example) to help you get started and has a lot of other useful features that Visual Studio doesn't have yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- The Left Navigation Drawer -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#E3F2Fd"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#818181"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

app_bar_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtNombre"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtDepto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtNombre"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup_CRUD"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtDepto"
        android:layout_marginRight="0.0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_Crear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="(C) Crear" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_Leer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="(R) Leer" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_Actualizar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="(U) Actualizar" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_Borrar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="(D) Borrar" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_Coords"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Obtener Coords" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cbxTracking"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup_CRUD"
        android:text="Localización en tiempo real" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvwCoords"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cbxTracking"
        android:text="Coords :" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/myButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvwCoords"
        android:text="Realizar Accion" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mylistView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/myButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="0.0dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Seems promesing, but a question, how can i implement this instead of the Main.axml in the xamarin proyect?, yeah, i'm very noob in this, thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not familiar with xamarin but please use these 3 xml files in your project and it will work and set contentview as activity_main.xml.